# C# thread and ShowDialog problem

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, showdialog

ProgressForm Class:

```
public partial class ProgressForm : Form
    {
        public int prc = 0, sz;
        MainForm mf;

        public ProgressForm(MainForm MF)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mf = MF;
            sz = 0;
        }

        public ProgressForm(int mx)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sz = mx;
        }

        public void SetMax(int mx)
        {
            sz = mx;
        }

        public void StartProgress()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void IncProgress(int prg)
        {
            prc += prg;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double pos = (double)prc / (double)sz * 100;
            progressBar.Value = (int)pos;
        }

        private void ProgressForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mf.isCanceled = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ProgressForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            StartProgress();
        }

    }
```

MainForm class:

```
void DeleteFiles()
            {
                int x = 0;
                int cnt = resultList.Count;
                isCanceled = false;

                DeleteThreadHandler("beginprogress");
                try
                {
                    DeleteThreadHandler("begindelete");
                    for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++)
                    {
                        if (resultList[x].isChecked)
                        {
                            DeleteThreadHandler("progress");
                            DeleteFile(resultList[x].name, deleteForm.isDeletePermanently);
                            if (File.Exists(resultList[x].name))
                            {
                                DeleteErrorHandler(resultList[x].name);
                                isError = true;
                            }
                            else
                                resultList.RemoveAt(x);
                        }
                        else
                            ++x;

                        if (isCanceled)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    validity(true);
                    DeleteThreadHandler("enddelete");
                }
            }

            void DeleteErrorHandler(string val)
            {
                Action action = null;

                action = () =>
                {
                    errorReportForm.AddError(val);
                };

                this.BeginInvoke(action);
            }

            void DeleteThreadHandler(String title)
            {
                Action action = null;
                if (title == "beginprogress")
                {
                    action = () =>
                    {

                    };
                }
                else
                if (title == "begindelete")
                {
                    action = () =>
                    {
                        olvVirtual.BeginUpdate();
                    };
                }
                else
                    if (title == "enddelete")
                    {
                        action = () =>
                        {
                            olvVirtual.VirtualListSize = resultList.Count;
                            olvVirtual.EndUpdate();
                            RefreshStatus();
                            progressForm.Close();
                            if (isError)
                                errorReportForm.ShowDialog();
                        };
                    }
                if (title == "progress")
                {
                    action = () =>
                    {
                        progressForm.IncProgress(1);
                    };
                }

                this.BeginInvoke(action);
            }    


    private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int checkedcount = GetCheckedCount();
            if (checkedcount == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please mark at least a file first");
                return;
            }
            DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
            if (deleteForm == null)
                deleteForm = new DeleteForm();
            dr = deleteForm.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //if (progressForm == null)
                progressForm = new ProgressForm(this);
                progressForm.Text = "Deleting...";
                progressForm.SetMax(checkedcount);

                if (errorReportForm == null)
                    errorReportForm = new ErrorReportForm();
                errorReportForm.ClearMemo();
                isError = false;

                Thread t = new Thread(DeleteFiles);
                t.Start();
                progressForm.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

In progressForm, there are a progress bar & timer which update the progress every 500 ms.
The problem is I still can access the main form, I also try BeginInvoke but neither works
Anyone know what is wrong ?

Thanks

**EDITED:** I've found source of this mess, it's DeleteFile which use Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile. After replaced it with unmanaged code it works fine.

Comment: I think to answer that we nned to see the DeleteFiles function...

Comment: By "I still can access the main form", you mean that ShowDialog doesnt freeze the main window? Did you try it without the threading? It looks like problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. The intention of the code is clear. that said, you are starting thread before showing your form. So you can still access form as it is shown.

Comment: If you are using WPF its better you use background worker, it is much easy to implement and use and if you are making Windows app then use of delegates may help.

Comment: @Mario : updated
@Euphoric: it works without threading
@Int32 : I tried to prevent user from accessing main form while the thread is running
@user751975 : I use Winforms

Comment: try ShowDialog(this) so you no longer should be able to access the parent form

Comment: If you are passing in (this) to progressForm.ShowDialog, then I'd be tempted to put a breakpoint at the line progressForm.IncProgress(1);
and then using the immediate window, look at ?progressForm.Owner and ?progressForm.Modal

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 progressForm.ShowDialog(this);  // assuming this is the main form
```

Comment: @Irwan also the form where ShowDialog is called must be opened showDialog, otherwise you will be able to access that form

Comment: not the main form, but all forms after the main form, sorry for my bad wording!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what the cause of this is, but you'll have a better chance of discovering the cause with a bit of debugging.

I would try the following;

- When you run ShowDialog on DeleteForm, does this behave as a modal dialog for DeleteForm or can you still click the underlying form while DeleteForm is visible? If not, does it when you run ShowDialog(this)?
- Call progressForm.ShowDialog(this) and set a couple of breakpoints (1) at the beginning of DeleteFiles and (2) at line progressForm.IncProgress(1); When the breakpoints are hit, use the immediate window to check progressForm.Owner and progressForm.Modal

Also, what are you passing a reference to the current object into progress form for? Is there anything in the constructor of ProgressForm that could cause these issues?

Another thing to note on Modal Dialogs from MSDN is the use of the Close button. 
The following comes from;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx

> When a form is displayed as a modal
>   dialog box, clicking the Close button
>   (the button with an X at the
>   upper-right corner of the form) causes
>   the form to be hidden and the
>   DialogResult property to be set to
>   DialogResult.Cancel. Unlike modeless
>   forms, the Close method is not called
>   by the .NET Framework when the user
>   clicks the close form button of a
>   dialog box or sets the value of the
>   DialogResult property. Instead the
>   form is hidden and can be shown again
>   without creating a new instance of the
>   dialog box. Because a form displayed
>   as a dialog box is hidden instead of
>   closed, you must call the Dispose
>   method of the form when the form is no
>   longer needed by your application.

Comment: Updated. 1. DeleteForm act normally on ShowDialog() and ShowDialog(this). 2. Both progressForm.Modal return true, progressForm.Owner at the beginning of DeleteFiles return {MyProg.MainForm} while at line progressForm.IncProgress(1); return {MyProg.MainForm, Text: MyProg}

Comment: I'm sorry Irwan, I'm not sure then. I've copied your code and written a simplified version that works OK. It throws up some concerns about having form elements as member variables that can be reused. For example, if the modal dialog is closed via the Close button, it still exists in the background and so the next time it's invoked, the Thread is still processing in the background. I think you'd benefit from doing things slightly differently. Maybe look at using the Observer pattern to report progress and perform your threading via BackgroundWorker as someone already suggested.

Comment: For examples of an alternative implementation for progress reporting, check out something like;

 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648108.aspx (specfically look at the second half of the article entitled "Observer in .NET")

or

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792672/how-to-send-progress-updates-from-a-business-model-class/4828404#4828404

I don't mean to suggest that this is the only way to go, but I think it is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Mr Moose. I've found source of this mess, it's DeleteFile which use Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile. After replaced it with unmanaged code it works fine.

Comment: Good work for finding the solution to your problem and reporting the answer. +1